# How can a coded test be converted into recorded test

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, azure-devops, web-testing

I am using VSTS for performance testing and I recorded a particular flow for which the coded script was generated from the recorded script and modified. Now, I want to convert back the modified coded script into the recorded one with the necessary changes made to it. My assumption is that - the modifications done to the coded scripts are not reflected in the recorded script, hence the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated way of regenerating or updating the recorded script from edited code.

You might create a new version of the coded test from the current recording, then compare that new file (or files) against the modified code. Then hand edit the recording to do the same thing. Repeat the generation, compare and edit as necessary.

Comment: but this would have the risk of having the exact same thing which the coded script has. Human error risk will be very high in this. Is there any other way out? There should be some, hopefully.